# RateLimiter Java

Tags: java

Rate limiter has to comply with the spec:

> Every request comes in with a unique clientID, deny a request if that
>   client has made more than 100 requests in the past second.

Would be happy if you review:

```
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.TreeSet;
import java.util.Map;

public class RateLimiter {

    private static final int REQ_LIMIT = 100;
    private static final int TIME_CUTOFF = 1000;
    private Map<String, TreeSet<Long>>_client_requests = new HashMap<String, TreeSet<Long>>();

    public RateLimiter() {

    }

    public boolean isAllowed(String clientId) {
        TreeSet<Long> reqs = this._client_requests.get(clientId);
        if (reqs != null) {

            Long current_ts = System.currentTimeMillis();
            if (current_ts - reqs.first() < TIME_CUTOFF) {
                if (reqs.size() < REQ_LIMIT) {
                    reqs.add(current_ts);
                }
                else return false;
            }
            else {
                reqs.retainAll(reqs.tailSet(current_ts - TIME_CUTOFF));
                reqs.add(current_ts);
            }            
        }
        else {
            TreeSet<Long> new_client_reqs = new TreeSet<>();
            new_client_reqs.add(System.currentTimeMillis());
            this._client_requests.put(clientId, new_client_reqs);
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

Tests:

```
import junit.framework.Assert;
import junit.framework.Test;
import junit.framework.TestCase;
import junit.framework.TestSuite;

/**
 * Unit test for simple App.
 */
public class AppTest 
    extends TestCase
{
    /**
     * Create the test case
     *
     * @param testName name of the test case
     */
    public AppTest( String testName )
    {
        super(testName);

    }

    /**
     * @return the suite of tests being tested
     */
    public static Test suite()
    {
        return new TestSuite( AppTest.class );
    }

    /**
     * Rigourous Test :-)
     */
    public void testRateLimiter()
    {
        RateLimiter rl = new RateLimiter();
        Assert.assertTrue(rl.isAllowed("1"));
    }

    public void testRateLimiterManyReqs() throws InterruptedException
    {
        RateLimiter rl = new RateLimiter();
        for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {            
            Assert.assertTrue(rl.isAllowed("1"));
            Thread.sleep(5);
        }
        Assert.assertFalse(rl.isAllowed("1"));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I believe a `LinkedList` would fit this problem better. Add to the end of it, delete from the beginning. All such operations would be O(1).

Using `System.nanoTime` is better for comparing time than `System.currentTimeMillis` - which goes by the computer system time and can thus change in case of time synchronization.

You're using `junit.framework.TestCase`, but I'd recommend using `@Test` annotation instead.

You need more exhaustive tests.

Your `RateLimiter` constructor is the default constructor which does not need to be specified.

Comment: thanks a lot. How would you implement `reqs.retainAll(reqs.tailSet(current_ts - TIME_CUTOFF));` using LinkedList?

Comment: @rok Using LinkedList, that would be something like `while (list.peekFirst() < value) { list.removeFirst(); }`

Answer (score 2):

It would make sense to assume that a rate limiter is used in a multithreaded environment. Your code has no synchronization and will break on concurrent access.

Testing time dependant operstions by relying on the wall clock is hard (imposible) to get 100% reliable. You need to use a time provider that can be configured to return the exact values your test case requires. I think JodaTime (and other major libraries) have ready made tools for this